# PHP runs two requests per request when using rewrite rule

Tags: php, wamp, duplicate-data

I noticed that PHP has been inserting the same data twice, even with a simple query, below is my index file:

```
<?php
require("constants.php"); //contains database settings
$database = new PDO("$type:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $pass); 
$query = $database->prepare('INSERT into test (test) VALUES (?)');
$query->execute(array(rand()));
echo $database->lastInsertId();
```

The `test` table has an auto increment column `id` and a varchar column `test`. I'm using WAMP to run PHP and mysql.

Each request to the page inserts two entries with different values (from the `rand()` call). Only the first insert id is echoed. This behaviour is the same for Chrome, Firefox and IE.

It's caused by a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

I'm assuming there's a file like robots.txt or favicon.ico which is requested transparently.

Comment: is the PHP Page called straight away, or is it being fetched through Javascript or something else? Possibly javascript is making the request twice and you need a `return(false);` somewhere.

Comment: The page is called directly, it's the index file.

Comment: Could be run twice if you hit `example.com/somedir`, which then directs to `example.com/somedir/index.php`

Comment: The only things I could think of are an apache configuration that emulates what @Marc B describes or something double dipping further down the stack.  Can you post more of the code in its context?  What kind of data is it handling?

Comment: Do you have any kind of rewrite/errordocument rules that could redirect to index.php? Could it be the page/browser trying to load a different resource (favicon, etc...) being redirect to index?

Comment: @Damp - bingo - would upvote - post as an answer, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any kind of rewrite/errordocument rules that could redirect to index.php? Could it be the page/browser trying to load a different resource (favicon, etc...) being redirect to index?

Comment: Yes, see the post. Which resources are loaded with each request?

Comment: Probably favicon. If you have access to your logs, you can probably see it in the apache access log. Otherwise, you could always append the dump of the http requests in a file on your server to see what's accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a [form token/nonce](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html) to prevent this and reply-attacks.

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, but not relevant for this problem. This is purely development code.